# Calling an optional function in Swift

Tags: swift, option-type

I'm trying to work out a way to call methods dynamically by number. Here's a simplified version of what I'm doing.

```
class C {

    func a() {}
    func b() {}

    let f = [0: a, 1: b]

    func call(n: Int) {
        f[n]?()
    }
}

let c = C()

c.call(0)
```

When I run this in a playground I get

```
Playground execution failed: error: <REPL>:10:13: error: could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments
    f[n]?()
    ~~~~^~~
```

Yet if I run

```
func a() {}
func b() {}

let f = [0: a, 1: b]

f[0]?()
```

directly with no containing class it works as expected. What's going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is really interesting! I noticed that your first bit of code ran fine if I moved the function definitions outside of the class but kept everything else the same. From the error message I was able to conclude that when the functions are declared within the class they need to be called with an instance of the class. When you just call `a()` inside the class the compiler is automatically interpreting that as `self.a()`. However, when the function is stored in a variable (`f[0]`, `f[1]`, etc.) it needs to be passed an instance of `class C` (`self`) first. This works:

```
class C {

    func a() {println("in a")}
    func b() {println("in b")}

    let f = [0: a, 1: b]

    func call(n: Int) {
        a() // works because it's auto-translated to self.a()
        f[n]?(self)() // works because self is passed in manually
    }
}

let c = C()

c.call(0)
```

Comment: Yep. `f` actually is of the type `Dictionary<Int, C -> () -> ()>`. I'd still use optional chaining and use `f[n]?(self)()`, though.

Comment: Good call, I hadn't switch that intentionally. Fixed now!

Comment: Dash. how or where was you got it info ?

Comment: Nice. This is a very interesting way of showing that [Instance Methods are Curried Functions in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/).